# Databases, character encoding, PDFs and XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, character-encoding

I am having little trouble with character encoding.

**The situation**

A file is uploaded that is converted into XML. The character encoding of this file varies, however smart quotes, entities and, various ASCII may appear. Once this file is converted into XML it is stored in a database. Upon user request, the XML may extracted from the database and converted into an array where it is then created into a PDF.

**The problem**

*Character Encoding*. Right from the beginning, character encoding has played a major issue. I would like to know;

- What character encoding generally covers the entire "spectrum". For instance, a `&deg;` which is unrecognised when parsing the XML or a smart quote (`’`). The smart quote will turn into `â€™`, etc, etc.
- How to store XML in a database. Encryption is a possibility, however database encoding is where I am getting lost at.
- How to get the entities, smart quotes (and other characters which may cause a problem) to appear correctly in a database and with a `Å` in front of stuff.

**Attempts at a work around**

I have made various functions which "attempt" to solve my problem - converting some characters into another. However, I assume this is the **entirely** wrong way of doing it and I should be changing the character encoding.

```
/*
 * Converts smart quotes to ascii
 */
function convert_smart_quotes($string) {
    $string = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-32", $string);
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-32');
    $string = str_replace('&#65279;', '', $string);
    $search = array('&lsquo;', '&rsquo;', '&ldquo;', '&rdquo;', '&mdash;'); 
    $replace= array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-');
    $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    return $string; 
}
/*
 * Converts some entities to an ISO format?
 * 
 * Example  : &deg; => °
 */
function entity_to_iso($string) {
    return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES & ~ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1');
}
```

Ultimately, my problem resides in the fact that I do not know the encoding of the file that is uploaded. I had an idea of a `switch` that attempts to convert characters into something more database and "PDF friendly". However, much Googling has resulted in bitter work arounds or arrays that `str_replace` one thing to another. Is this really the solution?

Any advice, solutions or fingers pointed in a better direction are all helpful and much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hello mate, i have a similar issue did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the encoding of a file is a difficult problem, UTF is easy because it has a BOM at the beginning, but otherwise it is almost impossible to correctly determine the encoding type.

However, if the XML is properly formatted it should have the encoding embedded in it, and the parser should handle it nicely. I see you are doing a conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-32, this is not going to help at all because it simply makes the string a bit bigger, however it does not change the codepoints used to encode the characters.

So you should be able to ask your XML parser for the encoding of the file, then change it from that to UTF-8 (or 32) before storing and/or processing.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do one of two things. I would either just store the stuff without any encoding in the database (as a blob) so that the database encoding doesn't come into it at all.

The other thing you can do is not store the information in the database at all. Just store it in a file (name the file some hash of something that will be unique), and then just make a table in the database that stores the location of the file that has the xml. Then you can just serve the xml straight from the file.